# Linux NASM assembly linked list implementation

Tags: linked-list, linux, assembly

Inspired by all of the lovely linked lists lately, I decided to implement one in assembly language.  This code maintains two linked lists - one is a free store and the other is the active linked list.  Rather than allocating memory whenever a new node is needed, the Node is pulled from the free list and all of the pointers updated.  The data is then copied into the newly "allocated" Node.

This program includes a test driver which reads a series of NUL terminated strings (C strings) from memory, calculates their lengths and then puts a pointer to the string and the length into each Node until the end of list is found.

If there are not enough free nodes to hold all of the found strings, the program silently exits with an error code of 1.  If there is enough and there are no other errors, the program prints each of the found strings on a separate line and exits with a status code of 0.

The output is this:

```
Alfred
Barbara
Carlos
Delores
Edward
Frances
```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
%.o : %.asm
        nasm -f elf64 -l foo.lst -g -F stabs -o $@ $<
% : %.o
        ld -g -o $@ $<
```

The `Makefile` is invoked as `make linky`.

The program, which I've place in a file named `linky.asm` is below:

```
; 64-bit linked list implementation in Linux NASM

global _start                         ; global entry point export for ld

MAX_NODES   equ        300            ; this can easily be expanded

section .text
_start:
        ; first initialize the free node list
        mov        rcx, MAX_NODES-1        
        mov        rdi, [freenode]
        mov        rsi, linkedlist
        mov        rax, Node_size
nodeclear:
        add        rsi, rax        ; point to next node
        mov        [rdi + Node.next], rsi
        add        rdi, rax        ; advance pointer
        loop        nodeclear
        ; set the last link to NULL
        mov        qword [rdi + Node.next], 0

        ; start out pointing to our rootnode pointer
        mov        rdi, rootnode
        ; our string pointer starts at the beginning
        mov        rbx, namestrings

looptop:
        ; fetch the next string
        call        FetchString

        ; skip to print function if we are at end of list
        jrcxz        finish

        ; insert the string into new node
        call        NodeInsert
        jmp        looptop

finish:
        ; print all strings in the linked list
        mov        rdi, rootnode
morenodes:
        call        NodePrint
        or        rdi,rdi
        jnz     morenodes
        ; (rdi is already 0 here) 

        ; normal exit with status 0
exit:
        mov        rax, 60            ; sys_exit
        syscall

errorExit:
        mov        rdi, 1             ; return 1 (error)
        jmp        exit
; NodePrint:
;   advances to next node and prints if non-null
; Entry:
;   rdi points to memory location containing pointer
;        to next node
; Exit:
;   rsi points to string just printed   
;   rdx is the length of the string just printed 
;   rdi = 0 if we are at the end of the linked list
NodePrint:
        mov        rsi, [rdi]
        mov        rdi, rsi
        or        rdi, rdi
        jz        retnow
        mov        rsi, [rdi + Node.mydata + mydata.msgptr]
        mov        rdx, [rdi + Node.mydata + mydata.msglen]
        push        rdi
        call        printstr
        call        printeol
        pop        rdi
retnow:
        ret

        ; rsi = addr, rdx= len
; NodeInsert:
;   creates and populates new node in linked list
; Entry:
;   rdi points to memory location to which pointer
;          to new node should be written
;   rsi points to a string to be placed in the new Node
;   rcx is the length of the string pointed to by rsi
NodeInsert:
        push        rax
        push        rbx
        ; steal a node from the freenode list
        ;   [rootnode] = [freenode]
        mov        rbx, freenode      ; rbx -> freenode
        cmp        qword [rbx], 0     ; Q: nodes available?
        je         errorExit          ;   N: nope, so leave
        mov        rax, [rbx]         ; 
        mov        qword [rdi], rax   ; 
        mov        rdi, rax           ; rdi -> node
        ;   [free] = [root.next]
        mov        rax, [rdi + Node.next] 
        mov        [rbx], rax
        ;   [root.next] = 0
        mov        qword [rdi + Node.next], 0
        pop     rbx
        pop        rax
        ;;  fall through to NodeAddData
; NodeAddData:
;   add string data to existing node
; rdi points to an existing Node
; rsi points to a string to be placed in the new Node
; rcx is the length of the string pointed to by rsi
NodeAddData:
        mov        [rdi + Node.mydata + mydata.msglen], rcx
        mov        [rdi + Node.mydata + mydata.msgptr], rsi
        ret

; FetchString:
;   fetch NUL terminated string and calculate len
; Entry:
;   rbx points to start of NUL terminated string
; Exit:
;   rsi points to string start
;   rcx contains length of string
;   rbx points to next string (if any)
FetchString:
        push       rax
        push       rdi
        mov        rdi, rbx        ; copy pointer
        mov        rcx, -1         ; max count in ecx
        mov        al,0            ; look for NUL byte
        cld                        ; count forward
        repne      scasb           ; look for NUL
        not        rcx             ; tricky math to get len
        dec        rcx
        mov        rsi, rbx
        mov        rbx, rdi        ; recover original pointer
        pop        rdi
        pop        rax
        ret

printeol:
        mov        rsi, eol
        mov        edx, 1

printstr:
        mov        rax, 1                ; sys_write
        mov        rdi, 1                ; stdout
        syscall
        ret

; ==== data section ====
section .data

; this is the data that goes into a node
struc        mydata
        .msglen            resq 1
        .msgptr            resq 1
endstruc

; this is a node of the linked list
struc        Node
        .next            resq 1
        .mydata            resb mydata_size
endstruc 
        eol:        db  0x0a

        namestrings:        db  'Alfred', 0 
                        db  'Barbara', 0 
                        db  'Carlos', 0 
                        db  'Delores', 0
                        db  'Edward', 0
                        db  'Frances', 0
                        db  0,0

rootnode    dq            0
freenode    dq            linkedlist

section        .bss

linkedlist  resb    MAX_NODES * Node_size
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a few notes, mostly in micro-optimizations that even assembly language programmers probably ignore nowadays.

```
    ; steal a node from the freenode list
    ;   [rootnode] = [freenode]
    mov        rbx, freenode      ; rbx -> freenode
    cmp        qword [rbx], 0     ; Q: nodes available?
    je         errorExit          ;   N: nope, so leave
    mov        rax, [rbx]         ;
```

To compare to 0, I prefer to use a `test` instruction:

```
mov rbx, freenode
mov rax, [rbx]
test rax, rax
jz errorExit
; ...
```

Likewise, in NodePrint you use an `or` to determine whether a value is 0:

```
    or        rdi, rdi
    jz        retnow
```

Again, a `test` is sufficient here. The difference is that `or` will normally affect not only the flags (which you want) but the register (which you don't). In this case, you haven't actually changed the value in the register, but some CPUs will assume you did, which can prevent some instruction level parallelism.

When you're getting ready for the scasb in FetchString, you load a 0 into `AL`:

```
    mov        rcx, -1         ; max count in ecx
    mov        al,0            ; look for NUL byte
    cld                        ; count forward
    repne      scasb           ; look for NUL
```

At least if memory serves, you'll get marginally smaller code with something like:

```
xor rax, rax
```

This zeros the entirety of rax instead of just AL, but you don't seem to need/use the rest of rax afterward. Some processors also have a partial register stall that makes essentially *any* operation on AL relatively slow (though I don't remember if this applies to any 64-bit processors, so it *may* not matter in this case).

Although it's minutely more fragile, I'd consider whether it's worth replacing this:

```
    loop        nodeclear
    ; set the last link to NULL
    mov        qword [rdi + Node.next], 0
```

...with code like:

```
loop nodeclear
mov qword [rdi+Node.next], rcx
```

Taking advantage of the fact that immediately after executing a `loop`, we know rcx contains 0.

I think it's worth noting, however, that all of these are really very minor. Overall, the code strikes me as quite clear and nicely written.

Comment: With respect to `xor rax, rax` versus `mov al, 0`, `xor rax, rax` assembles to `48 31 C0`, whereas `mov al, 0` assembles to `B0 00`, so `mov al, 0` is shorter by one byte.